# How can I show a pdf in base64 in flutter?

Tags: image, pdf, flutter, dart

I have the content of a pdf in base64 and I need to show it in a container in a flutter application.

I'm trying to do it with the image, pdf and convert packages from dart,but I get an error with the image class and I don't know how to show the image.

```
List<int> pdfDataBytes = base64.decode(fileContent);
  Image img = decodeImage(pdfDataBytes);
  PdfImage image = PdfImage(
    pdf,
    image: img.data.buffer.asUint8List(),
    width: img.width,
    height: img.height);
```

This is the message of the error in the image class: Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but you have flutter package displaying pdf : [flutter full pdf viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer#-readme-tab-)
You can find [here](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/opening-a-pdf-in-flutter/) an example of using this package with a pdf asset.

Comment: Thanks, but the article shows it with a pdf file in a path, I only have the content in base64

Comment: Can't you store your content in a file ?

Comment: Future<String> _createFileFromString() async {    
    final encodedStr = "put base64 encoded string here";
    Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(encodedStr);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File file = File(
        "$dir/" + DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + ".pdf");
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file.path;
    
    }

Comment: where do you get the method? "The method 'getApplicationDocumentsDirectory' isn't defined for the class"

Comment: getApplicationDocumentsDirectory is from the package path_provider https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Answer (score 0):

This error means you have a duplicate import for Image.